# How to pass value of variable from one page to another using header?

Tags: php

how can I pass the value of `$_POST['login']` to variable `$login`, to use the value in the page `home.php` ?  using this code:

```
header('location:home.php');
```

Answer (score 3):

By using session-variables, like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];
header('location:home.php');
?>
```

And

```
<?php
// Home.php
session_start();
$login = $_SESSION['login'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SESSION` array.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

$_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];
```

After switching to the next page you can call `SESSION` variable with `'login'` key using:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

echo $_SESSION['login'];
```